# For Loop insert multiple SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert multiple rows of data into `ms-access` by SQL with user insert session. Once I implement it keep show SQL INSERT INTO error, I've checked all my datatypes are correct. Need some helps here..

Button:

```
protected void AddClassBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string clvl = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    DateTime Sdate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    int Nsession = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    string Stime = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    string duration = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
    string desc = TextBox2.Text;
    int teacher = int.Parse(DropDownList4.SelectedValue);
    DBconn.AddClass(clvl, Sdate, Nsession, Stime, duration, desc, teacher);
```

}

Method to insert SQL:

```
public static void AddClass(string classlevel, DateTime Sdate,int Nsession,  string stime, string duration, string desc, int Tid)
{
     int no = Nsession;
     for (int i=0; i < no; i++)
     {
         OleDbConnection myconnection = GetConnection();
         DateTime d = Sdate;
         d.AddDays(i * 7).ToShortDateString();
         string mysql = "INSERT INTO Classes (ClassLevel, StartDate, StartTime, Duration, Desc, TID) VALUES('" + classlevel+"', '"+ d.ToShortDateString()+"'. '"+ stime + "', '"+ duration + "', '"+ desc + "', '"+ Tid + "')";
         OleDbCommand mycmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, myconnection);
         try
         { 
             myconnection.Open();
             mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch
         {
             throw;
         }
         finally
         {
             myconnection.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: ... and what is *error text*? You've shown almost everything in your question except the most essential part.

Comment: Your Insert Into has a `.` character instead of a `,` character after the date parameter.

Comment: if you use parameterized query, you didnt have to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VALUES('" + classlevel+"', '"+ d.ToShortDateString() +"'. '"+ stime + "', '"+ duration + "', '"+ desc + "', '"+ Tid + "')
```

You have `.` which should be removed after `d.ToShortDateString()` and replace it with `,` . Also use Command.Parameters to avoid this problems in the future and protect you from Sql Injection.

```
string mysql = "INSERT INTO Classes (ClassLevel, StartDate, StartTime, Duration, Desc, TID) VALUES(@ClassLevel, @DateString, @Stime, @Duration, @Desc, @TID)";
OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, myconnection);

myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassLevel", classlevel);
// my advise is to not store date as string. But you should dicide for yourself!
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateString", d.ToShortDateString());
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stime", stime);
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duration", duration);
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", desc);
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TID", Tid);
```

Be aware the OleDbCommand doesn't have named parameters concept, so you **MUST** define the parameters in same sequence like in the query !

Comment: this is correct. date is not properly formatted when you directly pass it to the string query.

Comment: it still shows"Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." after i change the dot back to ","

Comment: fixed.. desc is reserved word in access thanks for your yesterday information :)

Comment: @JakeCube Don't just change the dot, also adopt the parameterised query approach. SQL injection is a real risk and not taking this into account is borderline reckless behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, Desc was a reserved word in ms-access.

May refer to this:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1